# Can Merton's continuous-time portfolio model be reformulated without a utility function?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, merton-model, continuous-time

Under the standard Merton optimization problem the agent maximizes expected utility
$$J(\pi,c) =\mathbb{E}\Big[\int_0^TU(c_tX_t) dt +  U(X_T)\Big],$$

where the dynamics of wealth of the agent satisfy
$$dX_{t} =
 \pi_tX_t\Big(\mu dt+\sigma dB_{t}\Big)- c_t X_t dt, \qquad \textrm{with}\quad X_0=x_0 \in \mathbb{R},$$
where $(\pi,c)$ is an investment-consumption ($\pi$ - fraction of wealth to invest, $c$ - fraction of wealth to consume).

Can the Merton model be reformulated without utility functions whatsoever, like how the Markowitz mean-variance model can? What does that, or other variants of the above, look like in math

Comment: The mean variance model also makes an assumption on the utility function, even though this is not always explicit.

Comment: The mean-variance model doesn't require the utility function or risk-aversion parameter of the investor. it is commonly reformulated to be solved purely based on statistical moments of the portfolio alone

Comment: This is incorrect. MV effectively assumes a utility function of the form $U=E(r)-0.5\gamma Var(r)$, meaning the investor only cares about mean and variance. Risk aversion also affects the allocation between the effecient portfolio and risk free asset.

Comment: your $U$ without the $\gamma$ is what I mean by the case of portfolio moments only. Even the closed-form analytical solutions of the min variance and max Sharpe portfolios omit $\gamma$

Comment: I second @fesman ; the MV approach has an implicit utility assumption.

Comment: then how can the utiltiy function in Merton's model be made implicit, not explicit